# Error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to make some sort of templated `Queue` class. It seems ok but I am getting 2 errors in the same line which I can't figure out why. The errors appear in the implementation file .cpp where I am trying to give the definition for the destructor. Here is the code of the header file of the class:

```
#ifndef QUEUETP_H_INCLUDED
#define QUEUETP_H_INCLUDED

template <class T>
class QueueTp
{
    private:
        struct Node { T item; struct Node * next;};
        enum {QSIZE = 10};
        //Queue's head
        Node *head;
        //Queue's tail
        Node *tail;
        int size;
        int maxsize;
        QueueTp(const QueueTp & q);
        QueueTp & operator=(const QueueTp & q) { return *this;}

    public:
        QueueTp(): size(0),head(0),tail(0),maxsize(QSIZE) {};
        QueueTp(int q = QSIZE): size(0),head(0),tail(0),maxsize(q) {};
        ~QueueTp();
        bool isEmpty(){return size==0;}
        bool isFull() {return size==maxsize;}
        int sizecur() {return size;}
        bool push(const T& t);
        bool pop(T& t);
};

#include "QueueTp.cpp"
#endif // QUEUETP_H_INCLUDED
```

And here is the definition of the destructor in the implementation file:

```
#include "QueueTp.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typename <class T>   //<-<-<- in this line I am getting the two errors
QueueTp<class T>::~QueueTp()
{
    Node *ptr;
    cout<<endl<<"Deleting the queue...";
    while (head !=NULL)
    {
        ptr = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = ptr;
    }
}

//......other method definitions
```

The errors are pointed above and the specific error messages I get from the compiler are the ones below.

```
error: expected nested-name-specifier before ‘<’ token|
error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token|
||=== Build finished: 2 errors, 12 warnings ===||
```

Comment: `template<class T> QueueTp<T>::~QueueTp()`

Comment: Can i remove somehow that stupid question. I feel embarrassed.

Comment: Yes, there should be a 'delete' link near the bottom of your question. :-]

Answer (score 2):

Please use "template" instead of "typename" on the line where you are getting the two error messages! I find that most of the time, an unidentified keyword or a real keyword in the wrong place often gives errors similar to an undefined type, the next symbol after it would cause an error.